# Can you recommend a selectable Javascript Timetable widget?

Tags: javascript, widget, timetable

Does anyone know of a js "time table" widget?

I need the following:

- Days of week in columns & hours of day in rows
- 1 hour time slot cells (or customisable)
- Ability to select multiple times during the week using mouse to highlight/select cells.
- Select times across days of week (e.g. highlight 6pm time slots Monday to Friday with the mouse)
- Select multiple times across single day (e.g. highlight 10am to 13pm on Monday with mouse)
- more than one time range selected per day (e.g. 0800 to 0100 and 1300 to 1700)
- programatically set times when the page loads (so they are already highlighted)
- Interrogate the widget for times that the user has selected
- Limit number of hours shown for each day, e.g. just show 6am to 11pm
- Customisable css / look and feel
- The user is not required to do anything else other than select the times they want (so something like [this](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml) is not useful)
- free to use

(I doogled it but couldn't see anything that exactly meets my requirements)

Answer (score 2):

There is a Jquery plugin called FullCalendar that will probably work perfectly for what you are trying to do. There is a new view called "agendaWeek" that will give you a week view with time slots for each day. Hope that helped!

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/